# SQL Server Express 2017 database size limitation

Tags: sql-server-express, database-size, limits

I have a database hosted on SQL Server Express 2017. The size was small like 200MB. Today I have copied 24GB tables to the same database from external database hosted on different server.

The surprising thing is that everything is working perfectly!
As far as I know that size limitation of a database hosted on SQL Server Express 2017 is 10GB. Can someone please help me understand what I am missing?

Edit: When I run: sp-spaceused on the same database I get this output: Database_size: 24510.38 MB

Comment: Please add below info in the question. Please check database size by running below command in the database --> use db_name
go
exec sp_spaceused
go

Comment: Database_size: 24510.38 MB that's the output

Comment: Are you using `FILESTREAM` or `FILETABLE` data?  Neither of those are included in the 10gb limit.

Comment: Can please run `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: Are you sure you connected to correct database. What is output of `select @@version`

Comment: @ScottHodgin Could you please explain what does it mean and how to check that? I am new to this

Comment: @Shanky The output is: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: )

Comment: Please check this for filestream --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115882/check-sql-server-2008-filestream-status

Comment: Yes I am connected to the only database that I have

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin when I ran the same command I got the same output as this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3115941/7895818

Comment: `Database Size` from `sp_spaceused` also includes `log` space.  Log space is not included in the 10gb limit.  When running `sp_spacedused`, there is a second result set that has _data_ and _index_ columns.  What are those values?  What does running `DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE); ` show?

Comment: @ScottHodgin Yes, Log file is also important because that is not included in the limit. I was about to ask this question.

Comment: @ScottHodgin data: 24942120 KB index_size: 1600 KB. Running DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE) showed: Log size(MB): 4.117188. Log Space Used (%): 30.65702.

Comment: What value you got in the value column?

Comment: What happens if you try backing up that database and attempting a restore to a test database on the same instance?  Does that work?

Comment: I updated my comment about DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE). And I don't want to backup or restore my database ever because it's just for short lifespan project few weeks so no need. I just want to know how this happened and whether it's stable.

Comment: No backup?  What are your going to do if the computer/server that this database resides on fails for some reason?  I think it would be wise to make sure you can backup this database up and then test trying to restore it.  The documentation states there is a 10gb limit per database, so something weird is going on.  It would be prudent to verify you can recover this database should the need arrive.

Comment: @ScottHodgin I tried a backup and it was done successfully and the size of it around 23.5 GB. I will try to restore it somewhere